# Get the depicted result procedurally, with interactive possibility as described, minus the equilateral grid ? Python, AN, any other method

Tags: python, modifiers, animation-nodes, mathematics, coordinates

[image: Manually generated in Geogebra]

**Strike four - Drivers...**
[image: Drivers...] 
No control.

The AN nodes will prove to be the best solution as I initially suspected.
Unless I'm missing something obvious, which is entirely plausible.

**Strike three**
I'm looking for the easiest way to coordinate the positioning of endpoints which constitute the pink lines. 
(The grid itself can be a separate object)

**Ultimate goal is to use just one variable per object to offset them from the origin, and have a function generate the "y" from the "x".**

Inadequate ideas I've had so far:

1. Array to create the points(vertices or empties) on the "x" axis, but then there's a problem of generating the "y" array with non-uniform offset based on a function.
2. Use the equilateral triangle to generate custom orientations by which to translate new objects (empties)

   - somehow automatically coordinate their positioning
   - then use the coordinates to string anything renderable across

**Strike two**
Can an array of linearly equally spaced empties be used in such a way to take the offset distances (of every copy from the original) and then create another linear array whose elements would be offset from the original by putting the aforementioned distance values through a function ?

The next step would imply connecting the corresponding empties, the connections representing the pink lines in the graph.

**Strike one**
Translating x values to y via f(x) as usual, but without treating x and y as coordinates, only endpoints of finite (pink) lines.

I looked for other solutions before coming back to Blender, but since it is an all out graphical application, and Python based, as are some of the other options which seem too formatted/specific in application,   there's no reason not to ask if it's possible.

**Since this question is simpler then the previous which was solved by @lemon , I'm confident the answer will come, as I actually dissect the methods used there.**

Comment: I do not understand this question. Are there perhaps examples of similiar projects on the internet, which we could refer to?

Comment: I don't think so, I've searched far and wide, and since nobody seems to be using the "ternary diagram" in this way, there is no formatted value input system that would allow the creation of the depicted graph.   The crucial functionality needed to make this work is the generation of a list of vertices (along the yy axis) based on a list of vertices on the x axis. After some more thought I believe this is doable using animation nodes. (Doable even without using any of the established axes).  @lemon showed me the AN light on an earlier question, but I didn't follow it diligently.

Comment: So you actually want to construct your figure as a geometry with python?

Comment: Maybe it's easier (on my brain/memory) with animation nodes, but taking into account that any action can be scripted in Python, I  accentuated Python.  Yes, though I don't see any other way. What troubles me is that I haven't yet seen anyone spawn a  wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)  within 3D view.

Comment: I'm confused, a line is infinite. Geometry (vertices) are going to be finite. Do you actually want geometry? Or are you talking about OpenGl/`bgl`.

Comment: Since the axes are such lines, logic dictates that it should be possible.

Comment: those lines make the alternative triangular grid (as opposed to the existing quadratic one) , and I need the intersections because that mimics the regular increment stickiness

Comment: So, in theory, you could just add a triangle like rjg suggested, extrude the ends of lines to very far/infinity and enable vertex snapping? Maybe there are just too many questions at once in this question.

Comment: That isn't the critical part though.  Nevertheless I can't see why it couldn't be done.

Comment: Whats the critical part, then?

Comment: I already described it. "The crucial functionality needed to make this work is the generation of a list of vertices (along the yy axis) based on a list of vertices on the x axis."    Though all of those vertices could also be on the same line/axis.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand this "hold" on questions, or how is it beneficial to anyone. Just because a few people reading don't understand, nobody can answer, not even the OP. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you entered your X and Y coordinates in Blender's own orthogonal space. Then a transform that would take them to your 60 degree angled axes, with  matching lengths on the new axes, would be:

- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> with a numerical entry of `sqrt(3)/2`, followed by
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Shear, Z axis, X ortho, by `tan(pi/6)`

Comment: I've got a blind spot I've only now identified, but if I'm understanding your suggestion, it requires the empties to  already be placed along the axes, followed by their coordinates/positions being transformed ? Maybe I need to totally reform this question and ask how to generate sets of coordinates in order to place arbitrary objects at those positions.

Comment: That's the fundamental problem, I've only now managed to articulate XD unless I'm having a crash right now and everything I'm saying makes no sense.

Comment: @t8ja , no Empties, just a first shot. These transforms will take any object, (in Edit Mode) from Cartesian XY to your triangular XY. So you could construct the object, or Y = f(X).. whatever .. in Blender space, and- then transform it to yours.

Comment: I'll test it out on a cube, but first I have to figure out how to enter the root operator

Comment: How do you enter the operators ?

Comment: @t8ja .. just state the problem (_one_ problem) plainly and simply. atm, what I see, is that you want an empty translating in X to drive another empty on the 60 degree diagonal.Is that right? That can be done with an object-offset array, for example

Comment: Yes exactly, but for multiple empties/objects at once. Though it seems the operation, as you described it, has a limitation of having to be manually deployed for every pair.  LOL I'm not sure why I needed this to remove that blind spot from earlier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

Comment: If it doesn't, you've got the answer, even though I'm sure AN can do it too and I'm in the process of figuring out.